# What is wrong with this reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, recaptcha, captcha

I have been trying to get this CAPTCHA to work for a while but i cant get it to work whatever i try to do.

When i changed !== to just != as someone suggested the form submission will go trough with a "TRUE" response when i press "submit" button for the form EVEN if press the reCAPTCHA box or just ignore pressing it. The output for var_dump($responseKeys) always gives a me "NULL" value also so i cant figure out what is wrong.

can anyone see why it's not working?

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $captcha      = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $ip           = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $secretkey    = 'SECRET KEY';
    $response     = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secretkey . '&response=' . $captcha . '&remoteip=' . $ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);

    if (intval($responseKeys['success']) != 1) {
        //echo 'TRUE';
        //echo "<br>";
        //echo var_dump($responseKeys)."<br>";
        //exit;
    } else {
        //echo 'FALSE';
        //echo "<br>";
        //echo var_dump($responseKeys)."<br>";
        // exit;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="span9 page_sidebar registerForm">
    <?php
    if (isErrors())
    {
        echo outputErrors();
    }
    ?>
    <div class="well">
        <p>
            <?php echo t('register_intro_text', 'Please enter your information below to register for an account. Your new account password will be sent to your email address.'); ?>
        </p>
        <form id="regerform" method="post" action="https://<?php echo _CONFIG_SITE_FULL_URL; ?>/register.<?php echo SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION; ?>" class="form">
            <div class="third">
                <label for="title">
                    <?php echo t("title", "title"); ?>:
                </label>
                <select autofocus="autofocus" tabindex="1" id="title" name="title">
                    <option value="Mr"><?php echo t('title_mr', 'Mr'); ?></option>
                    <option value="Mrs"><?php echo t('title_mrs', 'Mrs'); ?></option>
                    <option value="Miss"><?php echo t('title_miss', 'Miss'); ?></option>
                    <option value="Dr"><?php echo t('title_dr', 'Dr'); ?></option>
                    <option value="Pro"><?php echo t('title_pro', 'Pro'); ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <label for="firstname">
                    <?php echo t("firstname", "firstname"); ?>:
                </label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo isset($firstname) ? safeOutputToScreen($firstname) : ''; ?>" id="firstname" name="firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="thirdLast">
                <label for="lastname">
                    <?php echo t("lastname", "lastname"); ?>:
                </label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo isset($lastname) ? safeOutputToScreen($lastname) : ''; ?>" id="lastname" name="lastname">
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div>
                <label for="emailAddress">
                    <?php echo t("email_address", "email address"); ?>:
                </label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo isset($emailAddress) ? safeOutputToScreen($emailAddress) : ''; ?>" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="emailAddressConfirm">
                    <?php echo t("email_address_confirm", "Email Confirm"); ?>:
                </label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo isset($emailAddressConfirm) ? safeOutputToScreen($emailAddressConfirm) : ''; ?>" id="emailAddressConfirm" name="emailAddressConfirm">
            </div>
            <div class="thirdLast">
                <label for="username">
                    <?php echo t("username", "username"); ?>:
                </label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo isset($username) ? safeOutputToScreen($username) : ''; ?>" id="username" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            
            <?php if(SITE_CONFIG_REGISTER_FORM_SHOW_CAPTCHA == 'yes'): ?>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="PRIVATE KEY"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            
            <div class="buttonWrapper">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="99"><?php echo t("register", "register"); ?></button>
            </div>
            
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submitme"/>
        </form>
    
        <div class="disclaimer">
            <?php echo t('by_clicking_register_you_agree_to_our_terms', 'By clicking \'register\', you agree to our <a href="terms.[[[SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION]]]" target="_blank">terms</a>.', array('SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION'=>SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION)); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of verifying users is a bit different. 
`g-recaptcha-response` is sent through a POST request to your server-side script, 
and along with your reCAPTCHA key that you get when you sign up,
you pass that along to Google to tell if the user is a bot or not.
The response is a JSON response so we will be using `file_get_contents()` and `json_decode()` to fetch the response and decide what to do from there with our script.
This example will give you an idea to write your own code.

```
$response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'; 
//verify your site
$data = array(
    'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET', 
    'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
    echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
} else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
    echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";
}
```